# 自らの回答にお礼を授与することはできますか？

Tags: サポート

お礼を設定した後に自己解決した場合、自分で回答を書き、それにお礼を授与することによって信用度を取り戻すことはできますか？
関係ありそうな質問: [dockerでコンテナのルートディレクトリサイズを大きくする](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/31269/3974)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

自分の質問に対して自分で開始したお礼を自分の回答に送ることは、現状できないはずです。

もちろん、お礼を設定した後たまたま自分で回答を見つけてしまうことはあります。

しかし、もし自己回答にお礼をつけることによって信用度を取り戻すことができてしまうのであれば、お礼をつけて質問を大勢に注目させ回答を考えさせたあと、自分で適当な回答をし、自己回答にお礼をつけることによって、信用度を失うことなく「お礼」システムの恩恵を受けることができてしまいます。こういうことができてしまうと「お礼」の意味が薄れてしまうのではないかと私は思います。

このことに関してはMeta Stack Exchangeでも議論されていました。

- ["Should bounty be returned if asker has the best answer?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156030/should-bounty-be-returned-if-asker-has-the-best-answer) -- Meta Stack Exchange

Comment: 補足というか、他の人がお礼を設定すれば自分の質問でお礼を受け取れた気がします。(前に+500点のお礼を自分の質問で受け取っていた人がいた記憶が…)

Comment: @Myaku 要するに、お礼を授与する回答はお礼を設定した人が選べるが、その時に自分（お礼を設定した人）の回答は選べないし、信用度ももらえない、ということです。

Comment: 言われてみれば確かに、ただで恩恵受けれるのはまずいですね。なんか直後に解決してて、気の毒に感じたのですが仕方なさそうですね。